# Time spent in each slide during rehearsals in Keynote?

Tags: macos, ms-office, keynote, iwork

Is it possible to measure the time spent in each slide in Keynote, during a rehearsal?

Something like this feature of PowerPoint: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rehearse-and-time-the-delivery-of-a-presentation-8424270a-d865-4aed-a321-1d2dd656381a

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid that's not yet available on Keynote for Mac, iPhone and iPad.

---

The only way I could think of to do this would be to start a timer and record laps each time you switch to a different slide. From the result, you will be able to calculate the time you spent on each slide.

This (timing and lapping) can be done in the "Stopwatch" tab of the Clock app on your Mac, iPhone or iPad. (See [Clock User Guide - Use the stopwatch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/clock-mac/welcome/mac#:%7E:text=top%2Dleft%20corner.-,use%20the%20stopwatch,-You%20can%20measure) for more information and guidance)